# Are Microsoft products installed as a ClickOnce prerequisite maintained by Windows Updates?

Tags: clickonce

ClickOnce doesn't have native/inherent support for installing prerequisites such as SQL Server Express. However, the ClickOnce publishing wizard in Visual Studio 2010 **does** allow prerequisites to be selected and to be handled by a setup.exe that runs prior to the ClickOnce deployment process.

If I were to install SQL Server Express via this route would it be updated by Microsoft/Windows Update? (assuming that it is enabled on the underlying Windows system).

I couldn't find a definitive answer to this question, but I did encounter a comment that stated that prerequisite installs would **not** be updated by Windows Update:

[How about a bootstrapper package for SQLServer Express 2008 R2?](http://robindotnet.wordpress.com/2011/02/06/how-about-a-bootstrapper-package-for-sqlserver-express-2008-r2/)

> If you’re using ClickOnce deployment, don’t forget that it does not
>   install updates to the prerequisites automatically – it only updates
>   the ClickOnce application. You will either have to have your customers
>   install the prerequisite before they upgrade the ClickOnce application
>   (just ask them to run the setup.exe again), or programmatically
>   uninstall and reinstall the application for them, including the new
>   prerequisite. (The code for that is in [this MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff369721.aspx).)

Answer (score 0):

That article is referring to updating from one major version to another, such as from [SQL Server](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_SQL_Server) 2008 R2 to SQL Server 2012. To do that, you must handle it yourself. For everyday patches and updates, most of those are pushed through Windows Update nowadays. Of course, you have to make sure your customer installs them.